# AVAudioPlayer volume and difference with setting volume by iPhone buttons

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

when using the volume property of AVAudioPlayer the max volume is only as loud or low the user has set the iPhone with the side buttons, so instead it works more like a fine-tune for volume set by the external buttons - is it supposed to be like this? - the built in music player does not work like this?

Comment: may be to play two or more sounds with different volumes

Comment: Bala: what do you mean? I only got one instance of AVAudioPlayer initialized

Answer (score 0):

use [MPVolumeView](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPVolumeView_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of controlling AVAudio's volume